# How do I install Adobe flash player on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, flash, chromium

I have google chrome and terminal always write: you cannot translate the name of the machine.
Command not found... 
What I must to do?

Comment: Your question's title is OK (a duplicate nevertheless) but your text makes no sense at all. Consider editing and posting some relevant information like what you are trying to do, what were the expected results and what happened instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `sudo apt install flashplugin-installer`. However, Flash shouldn't be necessary at all with Google Chrome.

Comment: That command is deprecated and you didn't mention the need to enable the Partners repository. The one used now is *adobe-flashplugin* (it should uninstall the one you recommended if already installed). Please edit and correct your answer.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: Unfortunately it's not that easy, at least not yet. Please see the ubuntu-devel thread which starts with [this message](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2016-October/039529.html).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson In the system where I tested it it always removed the old one. However, the duplicate has a better, more complete, answer.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: Indeed, I didn't object to that part of your comment. But considering that _flashplugin-installer_ is actually installed on most desktops to begin with, it's not exactly deprecated, is it? (Canonical has made this unnecessarily complicated IMO.)

Comment: @CelticWarrior What are you talking about? That package doesn't exist: "Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate" on my 16.04 system. Meanwhile, `flashplugin-installer` works fine.

Comment: @AaronFranke You need to enable the Partners repository. And please read the answers in the dupe mentioned above. Thanks.